# Is there any way to modify an unmodifiable collection?

Tags: javafx

I want to remove element from an unmodifiable list which I obtained from FileChooser . But in attempt of doing so, it throws an UnsupportedOperationException. Can anyone suggest me any way to delete/remove the content from the list?

Comment: "Unmodifiable" means you can't modify it. What do you actually need to do? Can't you just create a new list with the elements you need?

Comment: The simplest way would be to create a new list from the original one. What are you trying to achieve? This may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I am trying to create an application for browsing and editing images. For that purpose I am using the method showOpenMultipleDialog(). When I try to delete any file from the list returned by this method. File gets deleted but the operation of removing that file from list of files throws exception.

Answer (score 10):

You can create new List

```
List<*T*> list = new ArrayList<>(unmodiableList);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you called the [`FileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showOpenMultipleDialog-javafx.stage.Window-) method to get this list.

The method description says:

> The returned list is unmodifiable and will throw
>   `UnsupportedOperationException` on each modification attempt.

To get around this issue, do not call any method from the `List` interface which modifies the content of the list (such as [`List.remove(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)).

What you can do is to copy the contents of the list into a collection such as ones offered by [`FXCollections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html) class. Some useful methods will be:

- [`FXCollections.copy(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#copy-javafx.collections.ObservableList-java.util.List-)
- [`FXCollections.observableArrayList(Collection<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-java.util.Collection-)

Since you can't modify the list, you can obtain a copy of the list and modify that as you wish, or you can [`Stream.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) the original collection and only copy over what you need.

Comment: Note these methods create `ObservableList`s, which may be more than is needed (`FileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog()` returns a plain `List`, for example). If you only need a regular `List`, you should use the `java.util` API, not the `javafx.collections` API.

Comment: @james_D you are right, I am using showOpenMultipleDialog() which returns java.util.List<File>. But then also I am not getting how to remove any element from such list.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution. Although it may not be right way to do so, but it works. What I did is ; I copied the contents of unmodifiable list into an ArrayList by using enhanced for loop. And then applied the method remove on the ArrayList. But please post a better solution if you have one.

Comment: Why not just use the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) that does the copying for you?

Comment: @James_D Thanks for this solution. I have replaced my code with this and it works well

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for that would be a stream. Use your `List` to create a stream via `.stream()` and then use `.filter(...)` on the stream to remove the elements.